# What is the level of security for PostgreSQL PGDATA files on disk? Are the database data files encrypted (if yes, then how strongly)?

Tags: postgresql, encryption, postgresql-9.3

If a malicious user gets access to the physical storage containing PGDATA, how secure are the database contents? If encrypted, would it be greater than 112 bits encryption security? I am asking this to fill up regulatory forms related to data security. Specifically in case of PostgreSQL 9.3 on Windows 7. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but: 9.3 will be [out of support](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning) in 3 months. If you are concerned about security, you should plan your upgrade **now**. Having said that: no, Postgres does not encrypt any files on it's own. If you want the files to be encrypted, then activate encryption in NTFS

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @a_horse_with_no_name. We would be upgrading to a longer term supported version soon. However, if what you are saying is true, then anyone with the knowledge of the PostgreSQL data files format (or armed with a tool that can understand the format) can simply read the data contents if s/he gets a dump of PGDATA contents? Is the database password just for authenticating the pgclients, or is that used as a passcode to encrypt the database contents on disk?

Comment: You are correct, but that is true for all other DBMS as well.

Comment: Anyone with physical and/or root access to the server's hard disk probably has a lot of different avenues for reading the data. That is about server security. It's not really worth it for Postgres to concern itself a whole lot about that.

Comment: Having said that, other databases do offer *at-rest* encryption. I don't know specifically about Postgres or any of its plugins.

Comment: @deceze: "at rest" encryption is pretty much the same as file system encryption (in case of Windows, e.g. with Bitlocker)

Comment: Related discussions [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/1503431293987-5979618.post%40n3.nabble.com) and [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/CAN6gwKy-%2B2J3beE4vTpCbOko0i9Scm_rJu0JWEo%2BcQQLCsjS4A%40mail.gmail.com) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167101) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/82193) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64132) and [here](http://www.pgcon.org/2009/schedule/attachments/129_Encrypted%20PostgreSQL.pdf) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41898)

Comment: Thanks a lot @a_horse_with_no_name and @ deceze for the information. The links are especially helpful. I think we have to look at disk/filesystem encryption as a solution for this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL does not offer data-at-rest encryption currently, even though there have been some patches floated on the list recently.

You'll have to make do with file system encryption for now.